# How to use which.min from another table by row

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to get data from another data.frame which has minimum value.

There are two kinds of the datasets which are card and log.

card

```
#    id      BSTN    ASTN    BSEC    ASEC
#    201557  151     150     60633   61302
#    201558  151     150     60159   60680
#    201559  151     150     44757   45149
#    201560  151     150     77551   77923
#    201561  151     150     61160   61606
```

log

```
    TRNID   ASTN    TIME
#    1   150     45140
#    2   150     61300
#    3   150     61600
#    4   150     68570
#    5   150     77900
#    6   150     79125
#    7   150     82477
#    8   150     82767
```

What I want to is that get the log$TRNID and log$TIMElog$TIME data to the card data with following function log[which.min(card$ASEC-log$TIME)]

With the for loop, it takes too long time since it calculates row by row. Is there any calculation without for loop?

The final result of data.frame would be like this:

```
#    id      BSTN    ASTN    BSEC    ASEC    TRNID   TIME
#    201557  151     150     60633   61302   2       61300
#    201558  151     150     60159   60680   2       61300
#    201559  151     150     44757   45149   1       45140
#    201560  151     150     77551   77923   5       77900
#    201561  151     150     61160   61606   3       61600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is rolling join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(log)
setDT(card)

log[, ASEC := TIME]
res <- log[card, roll = -Inf, on = .(ASTN, ASEC)]

# >res
#
#    TRNID ASTN  TIME  ASEC     id BSTN  BSEC
# 1:     2  150 61350 61302 201557  151 60633
# 2:     2  150 61350 60680 201558  151 60159
# 3:     1  150 46140 45149 201559  151 44757
# 4:     5  150 77950 77923 201560  151 77551
# 5:     3  150 61650 61606 201561  151 61160
```

Rolling join will find an interval in `log` for every value of last join column (`ASEC`) in `card`. `-Inf` means the next observation of `log` will be used to match the value in `card`.

Comment: I've always found it frustrating when these fancy-but-awesome joins rearrange the columns seemingly arbitrarily ... nice, though, code-golf wins (as long as eun lee is good with another dependency).

Comment: @r2evans I am also not very familiar with rolling join. But I know what kind of problems it can solve. It always takes me much time to figure out the right configuration :(

Answer (score 1):

One way using base R could be, for each `ASEC` we find the index of minimum value `TIME` entry in `log` and using that index return the corresponding `TRNID` and `TIME` value and add it to original dataframe of `card`.

```
card[c("TRNID", "TIME")] <- do.call("rbind", lapply(card$ASEC, function(x) {
               inds <- log$TIME - x 
               idx <- which(inds %in% max(inds[inds < 0]))
               c(log$TRNID[idx], log$TIME[idx])
}))

card

#      id BSTN ASTN  BSEC  ASEC TRNID  TIME
#1 201557  151  150 60633 61302     2 61300
#2 201558  151  150 60159 60680     1 45140
#3 201559  151  150 44757 45149     1 45140
#4 201560  151  150 77551 77923     5 77900
#5 201561  151  150 61160 61606     3 61600
```

Comment: thank you so much!! however, is there any solution to modify some concept??! I mean in now the TIME is larger then the ASEC, but I am trying to make TIME less than ASEC.

#    TRNID ASTN  TIME  ASEC     id BSTN  BSEC
#1 201557  151  150 60633 61302     2 46140

Comment: @eunlee I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Can you update your post explaining what you are trying to do here?

Comment: sir, I changed the value and edited value of TIME on your answer sheet as seen above before to now. please check it!!

Comment: @eunlee I have updated the answer, taking into consideration that `TIME` value is always less than `ASEC` value. Note that for row2 value of `TIME` is 45140 since it is less than 60680 and not 61300.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to compare the (absolute value) difference between all `card$ASEC` and `log$TIME`, I think an `outer` call is most useful here:

```
outer(card$ASEC, log$TIME, `-`)
#       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]
# [1,] 15162    -48   -348  -7268 -16648 -17823 -21175 -21465
# [2,] 14540   -670   -970  -7890 -17270 -18445 -21797 -22087
# [3,]  -991 -16201 -16501 -23421 -32801 -33976 -37328 -37618
# [4,] 31783  16573  16273   9353    -27  -1202  -4554  -4844
# [5,] 15466    256    -44  -6964 -16344 -17519 -20871 -21161
```

We can quickly reduce this (per row) to find the minimum absolutely value:

```
( ind <- apply(abs(outer(card$ASEC, log$TIME, `-`)), 1, which.min) )
# [1] 2 2 1 5 3

cbind.data.frame(card, log[ind,], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#         id BSTN ASTN  BSEC  ASEC TRNID ASTN  TIME
# 2   201557  151  150 60633 61302     2  150 61350
# 2.1 201558  151  150 60159 60680     2  150 61350
# 1   201559  151  150 44757 45149     1  150 46140
# 5   201560  151  150 77551 77923     5  150 77950
# 3   201561  151  150 61160 61606     3  150 61650
```